# Phone Number authentication in Strapi

Tags: authentication, strapi

I am using Strapi for my android app and I need to login user by their phone number. There are many auth providers like email and password, google, facebook etc. But I can not find any documentation about adding phone number authentication. Please help.

Comment: I need to ask some extra Q's related to a similiar query of mine. can I hv your email id? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible to do that.
You will have to use the **customization concept** to customize the `callback` function of the `users-permissions` plugin.

- Customization concept - https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/customization.html#plugin-extensions
- Function to update - https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js#L21
- **For example:**

First, you should define `phone_number` field inside the `User` model.

Then, you should overwrite `extensions/users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js` by add `query.phone_number = params.identifier;`  under `const query = { provider };`

```js
 const query = { provider };    
      // Check if the provided identifier is an email or not.  
 const isEmail = emailRegExp.test(params.identifier);  
      // Set the identifier to the appropriate query field.  
      if (isEmail) {  
        query.email = params.identifier.toLowerCase();  
      } else {  
        query.phone_number = params.identifier;  
      }
```

In this example, we tell Strapi that we can login by entering an email or phone number both are accepted.

And you can remove the if-condition and just write `query.phone_number = params.identifier;` if you want to login with a phone number only.

Comment: How to implement this in Strapi v4? I did not find anything of how to modify auth controller in the docs. Can you please tell me how? I am trying to modify auth so that it would use Firebase auth so in front-end I am just verifying user by OTP and getting a JWT to be sent to strapi. How can I implement this?

Comment: I could not find Auth.js file or the directory you mentioned. Should directory and file be created?

Answer (score 0):

I think you  can add some change to `auth.js`
that file is on this [address](http://strapi/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js)

you can see [login](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/authentication.html#login) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

@Ghadban125's answer is correct, though I'd like to add some more details.

Not only do you need to overwrite the `callback` function in `./node_modules/@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/server/controllers/auth.js`. You'd also need to register your new function in your `strapi-server.js` (the one that you create under the `src` directory, not the one under `node_modules`, similar to how you overwrite the `callback` function) which looks like this:

```js
const { callback } = require("./controllers/Auth.js");
const utils = require("@strapi/utils");
const { ApplicationError } = utils.errors;

module.exports = (plugin) => {
plugin.controllers.auth.callback = async (ctx) => {
    try {
      await callback(ctx);
      // ctx.send(result);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new ApplicationError(error.message);
    }
  };
}
```

You'll also need to differentiate the request's `identifier` between an email, username, or phone number. To do this, you'll need to edit your `./src/extensions/users-permissions/controllers/auth.js` file:

```js
/* left out for brevity */
const phoneNumberRegExp = /^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$/;
/* left out for brevity */
module.exports = {
  async callback(ctx) {
    /* left out for brevity */
    const query = { provider };

    // Check if the provided identifier is an email or not.
    const isEmail = emailRegExp.test(params.identifier);

    // Check if the provided identifier is a phone number or not.
    const isPhoneNumber = phoneNumberRegExp.test(params.identifier);

    // Set the identifier to the appropriate query field.
    if (isEmail) {
      query.email = params.identifier.toLowerCase();
    } else if (isPhoneNumber) {
      query.phoneNumber = params.identifier;
    } else {
      query.username = params.identifier;
    }
    /* left out for brevity */
  },
};
```

Comment: hey, can you update this pls ? or i can contact you on discord?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the same on this github repo - https://github.com/mayank-budhiraja/strapi-with-otp-integration

A user is authenticated only through the OTP verification and all auth requests are made using the JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done on version 4.20.3. The identifier is your phone number.

[image]

[image]