# Strapi Phone Number Authentication

Tags: authentication, strapi

I would like a way for users to login to Strapi by entering a phone number, receiving a text verification code and entering the code to my app. There is an old thread that talked about this [Phone Number authentication in Strapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682978/phone-number-authentication-in-strapi), but the information there seems to be in Strapi v3. Is this still possible in Strapi v4?

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully made it work, although my version only allow user to login with their registered phone number, no OPT yet. But you'll get the idea:

1. Create a content type, let's call it "homepage".
2. Open `node_modules\@strapi\plugin-users-permissions\server\controllers\auth.js` and copy "callback()" function, paste it in homepage's controller at `src\api\homepage\controllers\homepage.ts` (Make sure to convert it to typescript if you're using it). Change the function name to `login()`
3. Import the missing functions:

```js
import { getService } from "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/server/utils";
import { validateCallbackBody } from "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/server/controllers/validation/auth";
```

4. Find & modify the query in the `login()` function to look for phone number as well:

```js
            // Check if the user exists.
            const user = await strapi.query('plugin::users-permissions.user').findOne({
                where: {
                    provider,
                    $or: [
                        { email: identifier.toLowerCase() }, 
                        { username: identifier },
                        { phone_number: identifier }, // << Change to your field name!
                    ],
                },
            });
```

5. Add a custom route for login API by create a file at `src\api\homepage\routes\custom-routes.ts` with following content:

```js
export default {
    routes: [
        {
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/login',
            handler: 'homepage.login',
            config: {
                middlewares: ['plugin::users-permissions.rateLimit'],
                prefix: '',
            },
        },
    ]
}
```

6. *Important* Rebuild your Strapi using `strapi build` then start it, go to:

`Strapi Admin > User & Permission > Roles > Public > Homepage > login` < Enable it

Comment: how did you manage to make it work when you used import and not require statement, also export default and not module.exports? Also getService import throws "Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './server/utils' is not defined by "exports" in \node_modules\@strapi\plugin-users-permissions\package.json". Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @FarhanFarooq I'm using Strapi typescript, also you can find the original login function in node_modules to replicate it in your own API